# Tor 0.2.4.20 build fails on Raspberry Pi -

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to compile Tor from source on the latest version of Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi Model B according to the [instructions on the Tor Project website](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en#source).

I started compilation with `debuild -rfakeroot -uc -us` and everything went swimmingly for the first half-hour of compilation with ~100% CPU usage, until this happened.

```
gcc  -g -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-all -Wstack-protector -fwrapv
--param ssp-buffer-size=1 -fPIE -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing  -pie -z relro -z now
 -o src/tools/tor-checkkey src/tools/tor-checkkey.o src/common/libor.a src/commo
n/libor-crypto.a src/common/libcurve25519_donna.a -lm -lz -lssl -lcrypto  -lrt -
ldl
../doc/asciidoc-helper.sh man /usr/bin/a2x ../doc/tor.1.in
a2x: ERROR: "xmllint" --nonet --noout --valid "/home/server/debian-packages/tor-
0.2.4.20/doc/tor.1.xml" returned non-zero exit status 4
==================================
You need a working asciidoc installed to be able to build the manpage.

a2x is installed, but for some reason it isn't working.  Sometimes
this happens because required docbook support files are missing.
Please install docbook-xsl, docbook-xml, and xmlto (Debian) or
similar. If you use homebrew on Mac OS X, install the docbook formula
and add "export XML_CATALOG_FILES=/usr/local/etc/xml/catalog" to your
.bashrc

Alternatively, to build without manpages, use the --disable-asciidoc
argument when calling configure.
==================================
make[2]: *** [doc/tor.1.in] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/server/debian-packages/tor-0.2.4.20/build'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/server/debian-packages/tor-0.2.4.20/build'
dh_auto_build: make -j1 returned exit code 2
make: *** [build] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1357:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc failed
```

I checked that I had asciibook, docbook-xsl, docbook-xml, and xmlto installed and ran it again, with the exact same results.  Does anyone know what might be causing this?  Has anyone ran into this before?

Comment: Also, for anyone who's in a hurry, [this Github repo](https://github.com/gordon-morehouse/cipollini/tree/master/raspbian_packages) is a good resource for precompiled Tor .deb's that although not the newest, are much newer than what's in the main Raspbian repos.

Comment: That link no longer works, is there another one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turned out to be as simple as reinstalling docbook-xsl, docbook-xml, and xmlto with the command `sudo apt-get --reinstall install docbook-xsl docbook-xml xmlto`

After doing that, everything compiled as expected.  It's likely there was simply some network or disk error during the installation of one of those packages, resulting in one or more of them becoming silently corrupted and failing to work as expected during compilation.

Answer (score 3):

The error message says:

> Alternatively, to build without manpages, use the `--disable-asciidoc`
>   argument when calling configure.

When you use `debuild` you can't just enter `configure --disable-asciidoc`. You'll have to edit the file `debian/rules`. On [line 22](https://gitweb.torproject.org/debian/tor.git/blob/HEAD:/debian/rules#l22) of the file there is a section which deals with configure options:

```
override_dh_auto_configure:
    ! [ -e debian/micro-revision.i ] || cp debian/micro-revision.i src/or/micro-revision.i
    dh_auto_configure -- \
        $(confflags) \
        --prefix=/usr \
        --mandir=\$${prefix}/share/man \
        --infodir=\$${prefix}/share/info \
        --localstatedir=/var \
        --sysconfdir=/etc \
        --disable-silent-rules
```

You'll need to add a backslash (`\`) at the end of the last line and insert `--disable-asciidoc` as a new line:

```
        --disable-silent-rules \
        --disable-asciidoc
```

Now your compile run should succeed.

Another way to resolve this error is to install the package `asciidoc`. When it is installed the compile will run without errors.

Comment: Thank you!  That's exactly what I couldn't figure out yesterday - I saw the `--disable-asciidoc` flag, but I had no idea where to put it.  The package `asciidoc` was already installed though, which is concerning.  Let me try to compile after making that change to `debian/rules` and see how it works!

Comment: Darn...that didn't work.  I edited debian/rules and the compilation failed like this: `debian/rules:64: warning: overriding commands for target` `override_dh_auto_confi
gure'
debian/rules:23: warning: ignoring old commands for target ``override_dh_auto_con
figure'
dh_install --fail-missing
cp: cannot stat ``debian/tmp/usr/share/doc': No such file or directory
dh_install: cp -a debian/tmp/usr/share/doc debian/tor//usr/share/ returned exit
code 1`

Comment: I corrected my entry. There was a section with configure options in the middle of the file.

Comment: Damn.  I still got the `cp: cannot stat 'debian/tmp/usr/share/doc': No such file or directory
dh_install: cp -a debian/tmp/usr/share/doc debian/tor//usr/share/ returned exit
code 1` error.  I'm going to try to uninstall and reinstall asciidoc and see if that helps.

Comment: Reinstalling asciidoc didn't help, got the same error...now to reinstall docbook-xsl, docbook-xml, and xmlto, and see if that helps.

Comment: And reinstalling docbook-xsl, docbook-xml, and xmlto worked.  Thanks so much for your prompt and extremely helpful insight, @jens-kubieziel